# Windows service cannot find reference to sshNet

Tags: c#, windows-services, sftp

I am trying to write a windows service(My first windows service) that uploads a file to sftp using SshNet. When i install and debug the service i get the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2013.4.7.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I think when i build the application the reference is not being copied to the exe file. Not sure though. Any help would be great. Also I added the reference with nuget if that helps.

Comment: click on your reference and set its property --?copy local -true

Comment: I checked that and it is set to true.

Comment: do you find it in the installation directory? Try clean and rebuild

Comment: Ok so I was calling the upload function from another class. I added the code directly to the service class and it is no longer giving me the error. It is not uploading anything but I am not getting any errors when debugging.